# How do I use kactivitymanagerd in a non-KDE desktop environment

Tags: kde-plasma

How do I use kactivitymanagerd in a non-KDE desktop environment

I compiled and installed kactivitymanagerd, but found that it only counted document information and had no application information.

I checked the database, and all I saw was documentation